# When does $ ϕ(3n)=3ϕ(n) $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I think this only works for when $3\mid n$, but I'm trying to find a way to prove this.

I have tried the following:

- Assume $3$ does not divide $n$. Then $\varphi(3n)=3n$.
  (But how can I show this is not equal to $3\varphi(n)$?)
- If $3\mid n$, then $3n= 3^{\alpha+1}$.
  (But how can I show this is equal to $3\varphi(n)$?

Comment: If $3$ does not divide $n$, then $\varphi(3n)=\varphi(3)\varphi(n)=2\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Do you have $\varphi(m n) = \varphi(m)\varphi(n) \frac{\gcd(m,n)}{\varphi(\gcd(m,n))}$?  Since $3$ is prime, $\gcd(3,n)$ is either $1$ or $3$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One direction:** Suppose that  $3$ does not divide $n$. Then $\varphi(3n)=\varphi(3)\varphi(n)=2\varphi(n)$. Thus $\varphi(3n)\ne 3\varphi(n)$.

**The other direction:** Suppose that $3$ divides $n$. Let $n=3^km$, where $m$ is not divisible by $3$, and $k\ge 1$.

Then $\varphi(n)=(2)3^{k-1}\varphi(m)$.

Also, $3n=3^{k+1}m$, so $\varphi(3n)=(2)(3^k)\varphi(m)=3\varphi(n)$.

**Remark:** We used repeatedly the fact that $\varphi$ is *multiplicative*. If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$.

We also used the fact that if $p^t$, with $t\ge 1$ is a power of the prime $p$, then $\varphi(p^t)=(p-1)p^{t-1}$. (We only needed it for $p=3$.)